# Normalization of samples based on the controls when we have several groups

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

Let's say we have the following DataFrame:

```
data = {'Compounds': ['Drug_A', 'Drug_A', 'Drug_A', 'Drug_A', 'Drug_A', 'Drug_A', 'Drug_B', 'Drug_B',
                   'Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B','Drug_B',
                   'Drug_C', 'Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C','Drug_C', np.nan, 
                   np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
                   np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
        'values': [24, 20, 48, 17, 20, 8, 22, 16, 46, 44, 12, 38, 26, 16, 19, 23, 9, 39, 19, 24, 43, 6, 24, 46, 26, 15, 8, 
                  22, 22, 32, 23, 41, 8, 46, 29, 34, 34, 39, 32, 22, 28, 34, 29, 19, 44, 22, 17, 41, 19, 39, 27, 46, 37, 26],
      'identifier': ['Sample', 'Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample',
                    'Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample',
                    'Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample','Sample', 'Control', 'Control',
                    'Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control',
                    'Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control',
                    'Control','Control','Control','Control','Control','Control',], 
'Experiment': ['P1', 'P1', 'P2', 
                     'P2', 'P3', 'P3', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 
                    'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P3', 'P3', 'P1','P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 
                    'P2', 'P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P3','P3','P3','P3','P3','P3', 'P1', 'P2',
                                                                                           'P3','P1' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In the identifier column, we have both Sample and Control values.
We want to first:
Calculate the average value of the column 'values' for all the controls from different experiments (i.e. P1, P2, P3):

```
df_control = df.loc[df['identifier'] == 'Control']
z = df_control['values'].mean()
```

What is the compact form of the script above, if I want to write it in one line? may I use list comprehensive?

Next, for normalization purposes, we want to divide z by the average 'values' of controls in each experiment P1, P2, P3, separately, to get a normalization_factor for each of these experiments.

At the end, multiply the normalization factor of each specific experiment by the values of Samples belonging to that experiment.

What's the simplest and most straightforward way to do it?
Thanks for you kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df.groupby(by=['identifier']).mean()
Out: 
               values
identifier           
Control     30.384615
Sample      24.285714
```

and then:

```
df.groupby(by=['identifier', 'Experiment']).mean()
Out: 
                          values
identifier Experiment           
Control    P1          28.500000
           P2          30.769231
           P3          31.285714
Sample     P1          20.833333
           P2          29.000000
           P3          23.333333
```

The second has the following `MultiIndex` which you can use to access the data:

```
MultiIndex([('Control', 'P1'),
            ('Control', 'P2'),
            ('Control', 'P3'),
            ( 'Sample', 'P1'),
            ( 'Sample', 'P2'),
            ( 'Sample', 'P3')],
           names=['identifier', 'Experiment'])
```

You could now build on this as:

```
all_mean = df.groupby(by=['identifier']).mean()
spec_mean = df.groupby(by=['identifier', 'Experiment']).mean()
result = all_mean/spec_mean

Out
                         values
identifier Experiment          
Control    P1          1.066127
           P2          0.987500
           P3          0.971198
Sample     P1          1.165714
           P2          0.837438
           P3          1.040816
```

Now getting the data into some kind of flat structure (? the OP is not explicit about this):

```
normalization_factors = {idx[1]: result.loc[idx].values[0] for idx in result.index if idx[0] == 'Control'}
# {'P1': 1.0661268556005397, 'P2': 0.9874999999999999, 'P3': 0.9711977520196698}
sample_values = {idx[1]: result.loc[idx].values[0] * normalization_factors[idx[1]] for idx in result.index if idx[0] == 'Sample'}
# {'P1': 1.2427993059572005, 'P2': 0.8269704433497537, 'P3': 1.0108384765919014}
```

Map the `sample_data` to the `df` as:

`df["calculated_col_with_the_name_you_prefer"] = df["Experiment"].map(sample_values)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that now that we have the average of all controls (30.384615), we need to divide it to the average values of controls in each of the groups to get a normalization factor. For instance, for experiment P1: 30.384615/28.500000 = 1.066, which is the normalization factor for samples of experiment P1 (This should be done for each experiment). Then each sample value of P1 should be multiplied by 1.066, and at the end, the average be calculated. Note: I need to do it for hundreds of experiments (not only three) and that's why need an automatic pythonic way.

Comment: Please check out the last edit. I hope it solves the prob. Otherwise you will have to loop on your own to make the specific calcs you might need.

Comment: @Ardalan1 if this answers your question, could you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: I appreciate your kind effort and response. However, I have not been able to get the desired result from the solution yet. The problematic part is applying the right normalization factor from control to corresponding groups of samples. I think it may need an IF condition for P1, P2, P3.

Comment: To get explicitly what you wrote on the first comment, you just need to flip my example as `result = all_mean/spec_mean`. You can then fetch the values you look for as `result.loc[('Control', 'P1')]`. Check the last edit.

Comment: Yes, this part is fine. I get the normalization factors by dividing the total control mean to average control of each P1, P2, P3. The problem is: Now, that we have the normalization factors of the control from `result = all_mean/spec_mean`  (sample is irrelevant in this case), value of every identifier= 'Sample' of experiment = 'P1' should be multiplied by P1 control normalization factor we obtained by the first dividing step. The same for P2 and P3 and etc. And I don't want to assign the normalization factors manually, as we have hundreds of groups (e.g. P1-P200).

Comment: Id did yet another edit. The code is generic and should work for any amount of samples. If you're working on some paper do not forget to add me tot he author list ;)

Comment: So what comes to my mind based on your answer is: After calculating the normalization factor of the control, make a dict so that key is the experiment name and value is the normalization factor from groupby table. Then, we should iterate through the df checking the experiment names of the samples. For every row, when the experiment matches the key of the dict, the value of the sample should be multiplied by the value of the dict and be inserted in to a new column.

Comment: Great! The last script line helps a lot. The only thing is that the second line should make changes in the main df and not the sample groupby, because the actual raw sample values are in the df.

Comment: Yet another edit. Have you done any research on this?